# "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'" - when running 'clmm' comand from "ordinal" package in R

Tags: r, command, ordinal, statistical-test

I run a command from the paper "[Multilevel Ordinal Logit Models: A Proportional Odds Application Using Data from Brazilian Higher Education Institutions](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/13/1/47)" - from the supplementary material:

```r
ord_gllamm <- clmm(formula = classes ~ year  + rate_doctstudents_prof + is_federal  + (1|hei_code),
                   data = df,
                   Hess = T,
                   nAGQ = 10)
```

and I got this error:

```
Error in as.character(sys.call(sys.parent())[[1L]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I tried to change the type of "classes", but it didn't help.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I looked for similar questions, and I tried to change the type of the output variable.
I looked for spelling problems, and ran similar code on different data frame, but got the same error.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Is `class(df)` a data.frame? Is `class(T)` "logical"? What are the classes of all your data.frame columns?

Comment: In R, a "closure" is a function and the environment in which it was defined; this error is common when what is expected to be "data" is actually a function, such as `df` as a frame, but it not defined then it still exists but as the [`df`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Fdist.html) function. I'm not certain that's what is happening here, but make sure that `data=df` is correct, and that `df` is the frame you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The data and the code can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBv6msnV_yBapGmvOw-WRtb0oARzMxM1/view.
The problem is in line 142.
df is a dataframe.
when I run lm, glm, or clm the code is running.

Comment: “The problem is in line 142”: that’s not really a *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: This code is running:

ord_glm <- clm(classes ~ year + rate_doctstudents_prof + is_federal, data = df)

bin_glm <- glm(formula = classes_bin ~ year + rate_doctstudents_prof + is_federal,
               family = "binomial", data = df)